# ngrx/store throws run time error when using createFeatureSelector with a class

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ngrx, immutable.js

My application is built on latest versions of Angular, Immutable.js, NgRx;
I want to take advantage of NGRX's `createFeatureSelector` and `createSelector`. However, I can only seem to select pieces of the store by string. I've pulled the pieces of code out that are relevant (I think). I also added a plunker link below illustrating the issue.

When the application bootstraps, it throws an error that `Uncaught TypeError: <CLASS> is not a constructor`.

Things I tried and the resulting symptoms:

1. If I move the offending  into the initialState file, where the reducer is getting it's default state, the error moves to the next class down the construction chain. In the example below, `CopyRollbackState`(code below) is a class that contains two sub classes `CopyRollbackRemovables$` and `CopyRollbackConfirm$`; If I copy the first into the initialState file, the error moves to the second.
2. If I replace the top level class, `CopyRollbackState`, with a Immutable Map, the application fails to run with the same error.
3. If I remove all hard classes from my state init, e.g. use `immutable.fromJS()` method, the error goes away. However, I would like to use actual classes in the Store.

Thanks for any help.

e.g.

```
/** provider.ts */

// this works 
this.copyRollbackRemovables$ = this._store.select('copyRollbackRemovables');

// this fails with the below error
// this is one of the methods of ngrx i want to use !!
this.copyRollbackRemovables$ = this._store.pipe(select(_RootReducer.getRollbackRemovables));
```

_

```
/** _RootReducer.ts */

export const appState: ActionReducerMap<AppState> = {
    ...
    copyRollbackRemovables: fromCopyRollback.copyRollbackEntitiesReducer,
    ...
}

export const getRollbackRemovables = 
    createFeatureSelector<CopyRollbackRemovables$>('copyRollbackRemovables');
```

_

```
/** fromCopyRollback.ts reducer */

export function copyRollbackEntitiesReducer(
  state: any = initialState.get('copyRollbackEntities'),
  action: Action
): CopyRollbackRemovables$ {
  switch (action.type) {

    default:
      break;
  }
  return state;
}
```

_

```
/** model.ts */

const copyRollbackStateRecord = Record({
  copyRollbackEntities: null,
  copyRollBackConfirm: null,
});

interface ICopyRollbackState {
  copyRollbackEntities: CRM.ICopyRollbackRemovables$,
  copyRollBackConfirm: CRM.ICopyRollbackConfirm$
}

export class CopyRollbackState extends copyRollbackStateRecord implements ICopyRollbackState {
  copyRollbackEntities: CRM.CopyRollbackRemovables$;
  copyRollBackConfirm: CRM.CopyRollbackConfirm$;
  constructor(config: ICopyRollbackState) {
    super(Object.assign({}, config, {
      copyRollbackEntities: config.copyRollbackEntities && new CRM.CopyRollbackRemovables$(config.copyRollbackEntities),
      copyRollBackConfirm: config.copyRollBackConfirm && new CRM.CopyRollbackConfirm$(config.copyRollBackConfirm)
    }));
  };
}

export const initialState: CopyRollbackState = new CopyRollbackState({
  copyRollbackEntities: {
    meta: {
      loading: false
    },
    byBatchId: Map({})
  },
  copyRollBackConfirm: {
    meta: {
      loading: false
    },
    data: {
      templateItemIds: [],
      rollBackConfirmer: false,
      rollBackReason: ''
    }
  }
});

// CRM.ts, similar extend and interface as above class
export class CopyRollbackRemovables$ extends copyRollbackRemovablesRecord$ implements ICopyRollbackRemovables$ {
  meta: IPagedMeta;
  byBatchId: Map<string, List<CopyRollback>>;
  constructor(config: ICopyRollbackRemovables$) {
    super(Object.assign({}, config, {
      meta: config.meta && new PagedMeta(config.meta),
      byBatchId: config.byBatchId && Map(config.byBatchId)
    }));
  }
}
```

---

[image: Runtime error thrown]
Here is the transpiled code that is referenced in the error.

```
var CopyRollbackState = (function (_super) {
    __extends(CopyRollbackState, _super);
    function CopyRollbackState(config) {
        return _super.call(this, Object.assign({}, config, {
            copyRollbackEntities: config.copyRollbackEntities && new CRM.CopyRollbackRemovables$(config.copyRollbackEntities),
            copyRollBackConfirm: config.copyRollBackConfirm && new CRM.CopyRollbackConfirm$(config.copyRollBackConfirm)
        })) || this;
    }
    ;
    return CopyRollbackState;
}(copyRollbackStateRecord));
```

I have built a [bare minimum Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/oQb5327j6zNoNyfP2Ulu?p=preview) to show the error. You can see the error in the console when the plunk loads. In the case of my application, the error prevents the app from loading.

Comment: It isn't doesn't look like a constructor. Beware your naming conventions. Always use PascalCase for class names in JavaScript.

Comment: @AluanHaddad I think I am using PascalCase for all class definitions.

Comment: my apologies not being specific. I mean that the accepted convention is to use PascalCase for things that are used as classes. That is anything you `new` or apply `extends` to who's `prototype` you add properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I fixed this problem, was to move all of the `Class` definitions to a single file. In my case, I had class definitions in a *.store.ts file that relied on class definitions in a *.model.ts file. Moving all definition to one of the two solved the problem.

Still not sure where the actual problem lies. Maybe it was hard for DI to locate the correct class.